# problems with animate applied to each element of the id selection separately

Tags: jquery

Hello and sorry if my english isn't good..

I'm studying Jquery for 4/5 days and I'm trying to use it in a page I made. I'm trying to create a very simple animation in which some attributes of the image with the id=#opacity change with the mouseover and then come back to normality with mouseleave.

Now.. with another #id as selector, (#p) in this case, every single image works properly changing its opacity when the mouse is over. If I erase the other selector just the first image works and the others don't. Probably it's a stupid question but I'm really new to jQuery.

Thank's a lot.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        animazione();
    });

    function animazione() {

    var opacity = $('#opacity, #p');

    opacity.mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: '1.0',
        },350).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({
                opacity: '0.6',
            },200);
        });
    });
    }
```

Here there is the html part with the images.

```
<div class="container_5">
        <div class="grid_1">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/monitor.png" id="opacity" alt="monitor" class="ambits" style="margin-top: 80px;">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_1">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/rulli.png" id="opacity" alt="rulli" class="ambits" style="margin-top: 75px;">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_1">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/lucchetto.png" id="opacity" alt="lucchetto" class="ambits" style="margin-top: 100px;">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_1">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/cuore.png" id="opacity" alt="cuore" class="ambits" style="margin-top: 100px;">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_1">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/allest.png" id="opacity" alt="allestimento" class="ambits" style="margin-top: 90px;">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: For starts, you should only use one ID per element. If you want to have multiple elements and address them collectively, you should assign a classname to them rather than or in addition to an ID. IDs are supposed to be unique for each element, and if you have multiple IDs on a page, you're going to get unexpected behavior

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute of HTML elements defines a unique identifier for that specific element, so the values of every `id` attribute on your page have to be unique. You can't have multiple elements with `id="opacity"` because it's invalid HTML.

When you use `$('#opacity')` jQuery internally uses the native JavaScript `document.getElementById()` function, which will select only one of the elements with the specified `id` (generally the first in the DOM, but I'm not sure there's a guarantee of that).

If you want to group elements together and interact with them all at one time, use a `class` instead.